# Amcharts - Creating 2 chart instances in Amchart 3 on same page

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am trying to create 2 Amchart instances on same page. Here I am putting the data manually. But I use dataloader to load data from a php file using mysql outputting json. For that, I will be using 2 different php files outputting json.

I created an extra div with a different id. And created another instance of chart in javascript and changed the chart id in it. Problem is that it is still creating a single chart. What I am doing wrong ?

This is my snippet -

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, {
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("chart1div", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, {
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis tspan {
  cursor: pointer;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis text.amcharts-axis-label tspan:hover,
g.amcharts-graph-label-only text tspan {
  text-decoration: underline;
  fill: red;
}

text.amcharts-axis-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<h2>Second Chart</h2>
<div id="chart1div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `#chardiv` in your CSS to `.chartdiv`. Then add that class to the `DivElements` such as:

```
<div id="chartdiv" class="chartdiv"></div>
<h2>Second Chart</h2>
<div id="chart1div" class="chartdiv"></div>
```

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, {
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});

var chart1 = AmCharts.makeChart("chart1div", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true,
  "marginRight": 70,
  "panEventsEnabled": false,
  "titles": [{
    "text": "Click on Country to see Visitor details"
  }],
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 3025,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025, // to ensure that the smaller bars' labels are fully clickable
    "color": "#FF0F00",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF6600",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FF9E01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#FCD202",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#F8FF01",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#B0DE09",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#04D215",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D8ECF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#0D52D1",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#2A0CD0",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#8A0CCF",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "hiddenvalue": 3025,
    "color": "#CD0D74",
    "url": "https://codepen.io/"
  }],
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true,
    "addDefaultRules": false,
    "rules": [{
      "maxWidth": 600,
      "overrides": {
        "rotate": true,
        "creditsPosition": "bottom-right",
        "columnSpacing": 5,
        "minMarginLeft": 38,
        "depth3D": 0,
        "angle": 0,
        "graphs": [{
          "hidden": false
        }, {
          "columnWidth": 1
        }],
        "legend": {
          "enabled": true,
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "labelText": "Country",
          "fontSize": 14
        },
        "categoryAxis": {
          "labelsEnabled": false,
          "tickLength": 0
        },
        "valueAxes": [{
          "position": "top"
        }, {
          "position": "bottom",
          "includeHidden": true
        }]
      }
    }]
  },
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "position": "left",
    "title": "No. of Visitors"
  }, {
    "id": "second",
    "includeHidden": false
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "graphs": [{
    "labelText": "[[category]]",
    "labelPosition": "inside",
    "id": "label-only",
    "showBalloon": false,
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true, //hide by default for larger screen sizes
    "columnWidth": .6,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showAllValueLabels": true,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "hiddenvalue", //use hidden value to make labels clickable
    "includeInMinMax": false //make sure the graph doesn't affect the value axis min/max when zooming.
  }, {
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "fillColorsField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
    "type": "column",
    "urlField": "url",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    //invisible graph for the second axis
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "lineAlpha": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "visibleInLegend": false,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "valueField": "visits",
    "valueAxis": "second"
  }],
  "depth3D": 10,
  "angle": 45,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "classNameField": "Ctglabel",
    "labelRotation": 45,
    "minHorizontalGap": 50,
    "title": "Country",
    "urlTarget": "_blank",
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickItem",
      "method": function(event) {
        window.open(event.serialDataItem.dataContext.url, '_blank');
      }
    }]
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
.chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis tspan {
  cursor: pointer;
}

g.amcharts-category-axis text.amcharts-axis-label tspan:hover,
g.amcharts-graph-label-only text tspan {
  text-decoration: underline;
  fill: red;
}

text.amcharts-axis-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/responsive/responsive.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<div id="chartdiv" class="chartdiv"></div>
<h2>Second Chart</h2>
<div id="chart1div" class="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Why adding class ? Is there any other way to solve problem ? What is the problem in the snippet which I gave ?

Comment: You don't need to add a class, you can use the element id, but you need to define the dimensions for each container the charts will be displayed. The reason why your second chart wasn't visible is that its dimension was 0 width, 0 height. `#chardiv` was counting only for the first chart.